# Sanity query always return empty array

Tags: javascript, http, next.js, sanity

I have two published posts. Localhost and my domain name are both in Sanity's CORS settings.
Sanity always return an empty array.
Here is my Client:

```js
export default SanityClient({
  projectId: "******",
  dataset: "production",
  useCdn: true,
  apiVersion: "2021-10-21",
})
```

And here is how I use it in my NextJS inside a getStaticProps

```js
  const query = `*` // also tried with `*[_type == "post"]`
  return client.fetch(query).then((posts) => {
    console.log("data => ", posts)
    return {
      props: { posts },
    }
  })
```

[image]

Comment: note that I have already published my documents

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. I needed to switch the project from private to public. It's a blog by the way.
[image]